# error in inserting data to database

Tags: java, mysql

Here's my code for createFood DA so that can insert to database. However , there is a nullPointerException at 
          pstmt.setString(2, food.getFoodName());

```
       public static int createFood(Food food) {
       // declare local variables
       int orderID ;
        DBController db = new DBController();
       String dbQuery;
       PreparedStatement pstmt;

    // step 1 - establish connection to database
    db.getConnection();

    // step 2 - declare the SQL statement
    dbQuery = "INSERT INTO orderitems (orderId, foodName, foodPrice, quantity,) VALUES(?,?,?,? )";
    pstmt = (PreparedStatement) db.getPreparedStatement(dbQuery);
    orderID = getNextOrderId();
    // step 3 - to insert record using executeUpdate method
    try {
        pstmt.setInt(1,orderID );
        pstmt.setString(2, food.getFoodName()); 
       pstmt.setDouble(3 ,food.getFoodPrice());
        pstmt.setInt(4, food.getQuantity());


        if (pstmt.executeUpdate() == 1) 
            return orderID;
        pstmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // step 4 - close connection
    db.terminate();


    return -1;
}
```

This is the code when i click on "orders".

```
      private void actionPerformedOrder() {
    //retrieve user input
    String numPax = (String) cbNoPax.getSelectedItem();
    String tableNo= (String)cb_tableno.getSelectedItem();
     java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
     Date orderDate = new Date(utilDate.getTime());
     System.out.println("Date   " + orderDate);
       orders = new Orders(Integer.parseInt(tableNo),Integer.parseInt(numPax),     (java.sql.Date) orderDate, totalAmount);
     int orderID = OrdersDA.createOrders(orders);

    OrderItems od;
   for (Food fd: foodList) {
       od = new OrderItems(orderID, fd.getFoodName(),  fd.getQuantity(), fd.getFoodPrice());
       FoodDA.createFood(food);
   }
```

I still cannot figure out the error. Anyone knows where went wrong ? Much help will be appreciated.

Comment: what does `food.getFoodName()` returns , it should be causing the NPE

Comment: `FoodDA.createFood(food)` should probably be passing the variable `fd`. The variable `food` is null

Answer (score 0):

You have passed `createFood()` method `food` variable which i cant see declare anywhere 
try 
`createFood(fd)` according to your code.